# Why are some processes shown in pstree not shown in ps -ef?

Tags: linux, shell, pstree

As title, I run the above commands in sh shell of Linux, but I just cannot find the the child processes of pid 7459 by running "ps -ef | grep dummy".
    Can someone explain why there could be such difference between these 2 commands?
    They are active processes ,not LWP(thread), right? How can I display the threads,btw?

```
sh-3.2$ pstree -p  7459
dummy(7459)-+-{dummy}(7508)
            |-{dummy}(7528)
            |-{dummy}(7529)
            |-{dummy}(7530)
            |-{dummy}(7551)
            |-{dummy}(7552)
            |-{dummy}(7553)
            `-{dummy}(7554)
sh-3.2$ ps -ef | grep dummy
root      7459  7167  0 Aug28 ?        00:09:13 /usr/bin/dummy
erv      23720 17254  0 13:22 pts/4    00:00:00 grep dummy
sh-3.2$
```

Comment: This is covered in the documentation(man page) for pstree. "  Child threads of a process are found under the parent process and are shown with the process name in curly braces", and similarly the man page for ps tells how to display threads.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @nos has already said, `pstree` displays threads by default, but `ps -ef` does not.

`ps` can show threads, you just didn't ask it to. Try this (it might depend what version you have):

```
ps -eLf
```

This is all in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps).

Linux threads are merely processes that share the same address space as another process. It's like a fork that didn't break away cleanly. You can read more in the [`clone` syscall documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone).

Comment: Thanks, @nos and ams. I think your answers are correct!
This is the first time I raise a question here and I am glad answers come so quickly. I will refer to the man page you mentioned carefully.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. Your next step is to accept the answer.